Logs not printed for Strimzi Kafkaconnect message transformer
I am using Strimzi kafkaconnect I have created Message Transformer but its logs are not getting printied in console how can i get those logs ?
following is log4j.properties file inside opt/kafka/custom-config folder
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %p %X{connector.context}%m (%c) [%t]%n
connect.root.logger.level=INFO
log4j.rootLogger=${connect.root.logger.level}, CONSOLE
log4j.logger.org.reflections=ERROR


I don't think connect.root.logger does what you want
